# Creating params hash via ajax post method

Tags: ruby, ajax, sinatra, parameters

So i want to create a custom params hash, but im not sure how to do it. I crated a ruby hash(kinda). I had no other ideas

```
$("#bt-dw , #bt-up").click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var id =  $(this).parent().attr("value");
  var up = $(this).attr("value");

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/vote",
    data: "{:entry_id => '" + id + "',:up => '" + up + "'}",
    success: function () {
      console.log("post successful");
    },
    error: function () {
      console.log("post unsuccessful");
    }
  });
})
```

the post controller

```
post '/vote' do
  @entry = Entry.get!(params[:entry_id]) rescue halt(404)
  @entry.vote(request.ip, params[:up] != 'false')
end
```

Comment: In your ruby controller, what is the structure of the params object you are expecting? I can tell you that your current approach will not work. Ruby doesn't just evaluate the string `{:entry_key => "<id>", :up => "<id>"}` into a hash if it finds it in request's url There's a special syntax for passing value in params: `http://localhost:9292/route?key=val&other_key=otherval`

Comment: But isnt the structure http://localhost:9292/route?key=val&other_key=otherval only applicable for the get request?

Comment: just placed my controller upside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from your comment it looks like you are just creating a single-level `params` hash.

It would be a little more complicated if you wanted to send an array or hash as a param value.

There are two ways to go about this.

Option 1: use this value for `data` in the ajax request

```
data: { entry_id: id, up: up }
```

Option 2: include the same information in the url instead of in `data`:

```
url: `/vote?entry_id=${id}&up=${up}`
```

Note that I'm using ES6 template strings here; this is equivalent to:

```
url: ( "/vote?entry_id=" + id + "&up=" + up )
```